# Threefold repetition: Am I getting it right?

Tags: rules, threefold-repetition

[image: Threefold repetition animation]

I was wondering if this is the right way of how the threefold repetition works. Thanks. (The image is in gif format, it should play automatically.)

Comment: In your gif the position is repeated *four* times. Black can claim a draw when the counter is at 2.

Comment: Leo, you have voted as "Best Answer" an answer which has been downvoted by 3 different people, because it _incorrectly demonstrates when a draw may be claimed,_ causing readers to believe that more occurrences are needed than are, in fact, required. This is, strictly speaking, misinformation, and should not remain designated as the "best answer" when these facts reveal that it is not a good answer.

Comment: Insufficient information about the position. It might be ok, or the draw could have been claimed a move earlier already.

Comment: This animation is horrible, it'd be better to use the traditional move format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion regarding the right to claim a draw when the position occurs 3 times results from the common misnomer for the situation: "*Three-Fold Repetition*".  A correct term could be *Three-Fold* ***Occurrence***.

As a result, in your diagram, after there have been 2 repetitions (which shows in the animation as "Repitition (sic) 2", there have been 3 occurrences of the position, and a draw may be *claimed*.  The game is not actually "drawn" until a claim is made and the Arbiter or Tournament Director approves the claim. This also has the result that if the player creating the 3rd occurrence of the position neglects to make the claim and proceeds to make a move, the right to claim a draw for this situation expires instantly, with his move.

Note that the protocol for making such a claim must be (to avoid causing his right to claim to expire) the following: The player announces his intention to make the move and cause the 3-fold occurrence, makes the claim to the TD before moving, and the claim is adjudicated. The rules do not describe whether the TD will require the player to make the move, but it would seem that he must, for the claim to be completed, or he will not have fulfilled his claim by causing the position to appear.  If it is determined (after the move has been made, presumably) that the position is *not* in fact a third occurrence, presumably his move must stand, and a penalty for incorrect claim would be levied.

Note that ***all of the legal moves in all of the 3 occurrences must be identical***, including rights to castle as well as any possibility of en passant capture.  It is *not sufficient* that the same pieces merely appear on the same squares.

Comment: Because of your last sentence, it is not sure if the claim could be made any earlier. :)

Comment: The player has to write down the intended move and that is sufficient for the claim to be accepted. It's moot whether the move is actually played on the board in the event of a successful claim.

Comment: For the last paragraph you could also mention that the same player must have the move!

Comment: @M.M It shouldn't be necessary. If all of the legal moves match, then the same player must be on move.

Comment: @M.M Your point about writing the intended move only works if the TD intends to approve the claim. What if they do not? Then they must require that the player make the move, since that is in fact what the rule requires; that _the position recur on the board_.  Only when the move is made can the claim be disallowed, and a penalty then enforced (and there certainly is one for such an invalid claim). So, I respectfully disagree.

Comment: @jaxter If the claim is rejected then the player must make the move that was written.  But if the claim is accepted, the game ends. Therefore the player does not have to make the move, since the game has ended already.